# How does the XP system work in Borderlands 2

Tags: borderlands-2

I have been playing Borderlands 2 for the last couple of weeks now, but I still do not know how the XP system works. I try to Google for some information but I only find XP glitch information. I do not know why people want to do that.

Is there a list of enemies with the amount of XP they drop, that would be nice to know. Also I noticed that the amount of XP you get depend on the level gap between you and the enemy, there must be some calculations on that.

The **main thing I want to know** is this:

- Do you gain more XP depending on the method used? (gun type / grenade / element)
- Do you gain more XP from a critical kill?
- If one of these above apply to enemies, do they also apply to bosses?

Comment: The amount of XP that you get is primarily dependent on your level relative to that of your enemy.  Other than that, I can't tell you much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XP gained depends primarily on the type of enemy and their level. Base XP bumps vary from ~100 for regular enemies to ~1,000 for "quest bosses" and up. XP is then scaled down if you are in a vehicle or if you are matched in level or better.

That's all. No XP bonuses for being underleveled, no XP bonuses from headshots, no XP changes from grenades, etc.

Comment: To elaborate: you get decreased experience by killing non-vehicle enemies from a vehicle. Experience for destroying vehicles is always full.